# Way of combining drawables?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, drawable

I am new to Java and Android programming and I am having trouble with my app. I have various ImageViews with their pictures set as PNGs from the res folder (using .setImageResource), I have another PNG, which is essentially a transparent square with a red border, which I would like to place on top of the ImageViews giving a highlight effect. I can't work out how to combine the two PNGs to give the desired highlighted look.

I have tried creating a new bitmap and drawing the highlighted image over the top of the ImageView's background but I couldn't work out how to convert the drawables to bitmaps.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just add another image view over previous image view in relative layout in XML . And set both the images.

Comment: did you mean via code? if so you'll need to go over each pixels and blend them together, and out put as bitmap.